# Grails - Trying to remove objects, but they come back

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes, Job and Description, in a simple one to many relationship:

Job.groovy

```
class Job {
    static hasMany = [descriptions: Description]

    static mapping = {
        descriptions lazy: false
    }
}
```

Description.groovy

```
class Description {
    static belongsTo = [job: Job]
}
```

I have two controller actions:

```
def removeDescriptionFromJob(Long id) {
    def jobInstance = Job.get(id)

    System.out.println("before remove: " + jobInstance.descriptions.toString())

    def description = jobInstance.descriptions.find { true }
    jobInstance.removeFromDescriptions(description)
    jobInstance.save(flush: true)

    System.out.println("after remove: " + jobInstance.descriptions.toString())

    redirect(action: "show", id: id)
}

def show(Long id) {
    def jobInstance = Job.get(id)
    System.out.println("in show: " + jobInstance.descriptions.toString())
}
```

This is what gets printed when I submit a request to removeDescriptionFromJob:

```
before remove: [myapp.Description : 1]
after remove: []
in show: [myapp.Description : 1]
```

Why does the Description get removed in the removeDescriptionFromJob action, only to come back immediately afterwards in the show action?

Comment: Do you want the description to be deleted, or just disassociated with the job?

Comment: I want it to be deleted, although disassociation might work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeFromDescriptions` did remove the relationship of `jobInstance` from `description`, but the entity `description` still exists.

`System.out.println("after remove: " + jobInstance.descriptions.toString())`

would result no o/p since the relation is non-existing. In place of the above line try to get the description object directly like:

```
System.out.println("after remove: " + Description.get(//id you just disassociated))
```

You would get the description successfully.

To avoid that, you need to add the below mapping property  to `Job` to remove all the orphans once an entity is detached from parent.

`descriptions cascade: "all-delete-orphan"`

Like:

```
class Job {
    static hasMany = [descriptions: Description]

    static mapping = {
        descriptions lazy: false, cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}
```

[GORM Bible](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/) - A must-read.